# CISCO ASA: Add specific command to a privilege level

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

i am facing the following issue, created a new account with a "read-only" access on a CISCO ASA 5510. This account will be used in a script that will back up  the running-config of the ASA.

the commands I am looking to add to the privilege level are:

```
no terminal pager
terminal pager 24
```

I want the user to have nothing but read only permission, and these 2 command's.

Or maybe there a better/other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
privilege cmd level 3 mode exec command terminal
```